# can not install postgis in pg10/11 at windows os

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgis-installation

os: windows10 64x
postgres: v11.5 / v10.10
postgis: v2.5 / v2.4

when I create extension of postgis, it shows the error below:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "D:/PostgreSQL/10/lib/rtpostgis-2.4.dll":  
The specified module could not be found.
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you install the PostGIS software?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, isntall postgis by stack builder

Comment: Check if the DLL is there and all its requirements can be resolved. I used to use the third-party tool `depends.exe` for that on Windows, but there may be othet ways.

Answer (score 0):

fix by this answer. "libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" is lack of.  https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4482